# Framing an image in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, image

I'm working on an app using XCode 6 and I'm trying to frame an image. I have one image that will change dynamically depending on the selection in the prior screen. I have another image behind it that is literally an image of a frame. The idea is to have the actual image look like it is surrounded by the frame itself. Here's the trick. I want the actual image to be a certain width to fill most of the horizontal size of the screen (say 85% if you want a number). I want the image to resize to this width based on the width of the screen (based on iPhone 4 vs iPhone 6, for example; so the width sets based on the screen, and the height sets based on the width to maintain its original aspect ratio). The frame should be about 10 pixels wider and 10 pixels taller, leaving 5 pixels around each edge, and the pictures should be centered at the same point.

I've seen a few programmatic fixes for resizing things based on the original aspect ratio of the image. However, I've been primarily using just Storyboard and was hoping to get an answer along those lines. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use auto layout and add constraints to the left and right of the frame to the superview.  Then add constraints to the image inside the frame to be 10 pixels on top, bottom, left, and right to the edges of the frame.  The left and right constraints of the frame should leave everything centered on the screen.  Do you have any experience with Auto Layout? It can be a bit of a difficult learning curve, but for your purposes its a perfect solution.

Comment: So I've tried that, but just for kicks I deleted all my constraints and tried it again. I still end up with a ton of conflicting constraints. Part of the issue is setting the constraints so that the width is set first based on the constraints, then the aspect ratio, and then the rest of the constraints are set based on that...

Comment: Theres your problem.  If you are setting constraints to the left and right side, don't use a width constraint.  They are conflicting. But aspect ratio should be fine.  Delete the width constraint, leave left, right, aspect ratio, and center alignment and it should work for you. Also don't set a height constraint, because if you are pinning to the left and right with aspect ratio, it should set height based on the width from the constraints.

Comment: Got it. Got it. Not sure if it was 100% what you said, because I think that was what I was doing at one point, but it gave me clarity and it sorted out the conflicting constraints, so thank you for that. I think part of the issue was that I was assuming a slightly different aspect ratio for the frame image than was actually true.

Comment: Awesome glad I could help, feel free to mark my answer as the solution since the solution is in our comments :)